# AOSP Generating signed factory images and full update packages

Tags: android, build, openssl, pgp

I am trying to Generating signed factory images and full update packages for AOSP rom called copperhead os.

i have done the build now when i Generat signed factory images and full update packages with the release.sh script:

```
script/release.sh marlin
```

it asks for a password noting that i left the keys passphrases blank before the build process when i Generated release signing keys (blank passphrases for all of them).

i cant leave this blank and when i put what ever passphrase it results into

```
suhaib@suhaib:~/sdk/copperheados-N2G47X.2017.06.15.06.09.53$ script/release.sh sailfish
Enter password for keys/sailfish/releasekey key> 
Enter password for keys/sailfish/releasekey key> 
rewriting VENDOR/build.prop:
  replace:  ro.vendor.build.fingerprint=Android/aosp_sailfish/sailfish:7.1.2/N2G47X/2017.06.20.18.57.32:user/test-keys
     with:  ro.vendor.build.fingerprint=Android/aosp_sailfish/sailfish:7.1.2/N2G47X/2017.06.20.18.57.32:user/release-keys
    signing: imssettings.apk                 (keys/sailfish/platform)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UsePerfData
    signing: ims.apk                         (keys/sailfish/platform)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UsePerfData
    signing: colorservice.apk                (keys/sailfish/platform)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UsePerfData
    signing: SSRestartDetector.apk           (keys/sailfish/platform)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UsePerfData
    signing: InputDevices.apk                (keys/sailfish/platform)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UsePerfData
    signing: MediaProvider.apk               (keys/sailfish/media)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UsePerfData
    signing: ExternalStorageProvider.apk     (keys/sailfish/platform)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UsePerfData
    signing: Updater.apk                     (keys/sailfish/releasekey)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UsePerfData
signapk: Password for keys/sailfish/releasekey.pk8 may be bad.
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Cannot retrieve the PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
    at javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.getKeySpec(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:255)
    at com.android.signapk.SignApk.decryptPrivateKey(SignApk.java:243)
    at com.android.signapk.SignApk.readPrivateKey(SignApk.java:259)
    at com.android.signapk.SignApk.main(SignApk.java:1105)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:989)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.doFinal(PBES1Core.java:416)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineDoFinal(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:316)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.getKeySpec(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:250)
    ... 3 more

   ERROR: signapk.jar failed: return code 1
```

Comment: What is the problem or question? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i have entered accidentally a key when generating the build Anyhow tried to rebuild again with no key passphrases, this is solved